# taking in input from a file in java

Tags: java, file-io

i cannot for the life of me seem to take in the contents of this file, i keep getting No such elements exception on line 25, all help appreciate. heres a link to the file [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6jWxPwhFXHvYmhjSkxjNmQwRTQ)

heres my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practiceFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0];
        int length = fileLength(fileName);
        int[] array = new int[length];
        String[] list = new String[length];
        arrayPopulate(array, list, fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

    }

    public static int fileLength(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileName);
        int counter = 0;
        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            fileScan.next();
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }

    public static void arrayPopulate(int[] array, String[] list, String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileScan = null;
        try {
            fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("details: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = fileScan.nextInt();
            list[i] = fileScan.next();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your error is coming from Line 25 of your code. not line 25 of the text file. You should also paste the first couple of lines of your stack trace/error output.

Comment: What filepath do you give for the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here. First of all you are using `fileScan.next();` to try and get the length of a file. This is going to give you 2 times the length because you are counting each token `fileScan.next()` grabs which will be **first the number and then the letter.**

Length of lines is 144 but when you calculate it, it returns 288.

So use `fileScan.nextLine();`, now some people have mentioned this but your program is still not going to work correctly because you passed `Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileName); // mistake passed fileName instead of file`

**Here are the changes I made inside the fileLength() method:**

```
 File file = new File(fileName);
 Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file); // mistake passed fileName instead of file, changed from Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileName)

 while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        fileScan.nextLine(); // changed from fileScan.next()
        counter++;
    }
```

**Your output looks like:**

```
84c89C11w71h110B96d61H92d10B3p40c97G117X13....
```

When you are printing the results, change the print statements to

```
 System.out.print(array[i]);
 System.out.print(" " + list[i]);
 System.out.println();
```

**Output now looks like:**

```
84 c
89 C
11 w
71 h
....
```

Comment: Using `hasNext()` with `nextLine()` can have some strange behaviors in other situations. It won't cause any problems in this file, but generally the `hasNext***()` should match the `next***()` call.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Also I changed it to use `hasNextLine()`. But I see what you are saying.

Comment: If, for example, the file ended in blank lines, it would skip over those lines (that's desired in this though). Or, if the `Scanner` was using a non-whitespace delimiter via `useDelimeter`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using    int length = fileLength(fileName); to find the length, use     int length = fileName.length();

Comment: That's not at all what they need. That just gets the number of characters in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

From the format of your file and your current code, it looks like `length` represents the number of "words" in the file. In your loop, you need to advance `i` by 2 instead of 1, since it consumes two "words" per iteration. This also means that each array is twice as long as it should be. Instantiate them with `length/2`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    array[i] = fileScan.nextInt();
    list[i] = fileScan.next();
}
```

Alternately, you could make `length` represent the number of lines in the file. To do that, use `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` in your counting loop. Then leave all of the rest of your code as-is.

```
while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
    fileScan.nextLine();
    counter++;
}
```

Additionally, make sure your `Scanner` is passed the proper parameters. A `String` is valid, but not for File I/O. You would need to first create a `File` object using the `fileName`.

```
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```